# SwapExactTokensForTokens not working properly

Tags: solidity, uniswap, sushiswap

I'm building an arbitrage bot that swaps tokens from uniswap and sushiswap (or vice versa). To build it i used the `swapExactTokensForTokens()` function from uniswap and sushiswap, when i try to swap the tokens that i chose everything works fine but it sends the output tokens to my contract in a strange way. When i try to do `address(this).balance` it returns 0 but when i try do `IERC20(0x...tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this))` it returns a huge number: 5166934636149357031. Why is that?

**The full contract:**

```
contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint256 _flashAmount,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _flashAmount,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _flashAmount, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 flashAmount,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));

        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == flashAmount,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens = new address[](2);

        tokens[0] = _tokenA;
        tokens[1] = _tokenB;

        if (_startOnUniswap) {
            swapOnUniswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
            
            (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: IERC20(tokens[1]).balanceOf(address(this))}("");
            require(sent == true, "error while sending eth");
        } else {
            console.log("Ho 10 WETH e li swappo per x COMPOUND");
            swapOnSushiswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            console.log("Ho x COMPOUND e li swappo per >10 WETH");
            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );

            // address(this).balance = 0 eth
            // IERC20(tokens[1]).balanceOf(address(this)) = 6404762942178924475 ??? 

        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "UNISWAP: Input tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = sRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "SUSHISWAP: Input tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

}
```

Any help or suggestion would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but `address(this).balance` is the balance of ETH in the contract. `IERC20(token_address).balanceOf(address(this))` is the contract balance of the corresponding ERC-20 token. ERC-20s represent the quantity of token according to the `decimals` specified in the contract. For example if you own 1 of some token, and its decimals are set to 18. Then your balance on chain would be accounted as `1*10**18`.